# How to convert a System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush to a System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush?

Tags: wpf, winforms, gdi+, system.drawing

I trying to port
System.Drawing:
public LinearGradientBrush(
    Rectangle rect,
    Color color1,
    Color color2,
    float angle
)
to System.Windows.Media .  I can get the angle to be correct but I can't get the start and end to be at the corners. I have tried scaling the brush's transform but that ends up messing the angle.

[image]

System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142563.aspx

System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602517.aspx

Comment: Wanted to see if you could share your code on how you solved this. Running into the same issue now myself and I really could use as much as you can share. Thanks @phi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am calculating my start and end points using the intersection of the gradient axis (red line) and the line (blue) perpendicular to the gradient axis  that also intersects a corner of the rectangle.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The corners are good, the gamma correction looks different.  The WPF LinearGradientBrush indeed has a GammaCorrection property.  Play with it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the point at which you choose the gradient to start will actually be where the center of the gradient is if you are using System.Drawing.Drawing2D.  I could be wrong, but it looks like System. are using the beginning of the gradient at that point instead of the center which seems to be leading to a bit of an offset.